# i cannot compile my code because of this error message: mario.c:5:1: error: expected identifier or '(' { ^

Tags: c, cs50

The top curly brace under int main(void) is what keeps getting flagged.  The curly-brace cannot be the real issue because I know the entire code needs to be in between the curly braces, so it must be something else.  I have tried deleting and replacing the braces, I have checked the other code to make sure all the loops have braces as needed... I don't get it.  I have gone out and back int the program a few times over several days.
Here is the part of my code near the error message:

```
# include <cs50.h>

int main(void);
{
    int h;
// prompt user until user enters an integer from 1 to 8
    do
    {
        h = get_int("hight: \n");
    }
    while (h < 1 || h > 8);
```

Comment: Get rid of the `;` at the end of main `main(void);` => `main(void)`

Comment: int main (void); is the problem. remove the ';' character

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon on

`int main(void);`

Remove the semicolon and you should be golden.

`int main(void) {`